# Extend Django ModelForm with a class

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, django-forms

I have multiple model forms in my Django project and want to add three fields to all of them.

But when I write a simple form and then subclass it, I get an error.

```
class PersonForm(forms.Form):
    person_name = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Entregado por',
        max_length=64,
    )
    person_document_number = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Número de Documento',
        max_length=15,
    )
    person_document_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        label=u'Tipo de Documento',
        choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH + list(DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES),
    )

class ContractForm(PersonForm, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contract

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContractForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['person_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'js-person-name'
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I tried to define a `PersonForm` like

```
class PersonForm:
    person_name = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Entregado por',
        max_length=64,
    )
    # ....
```

without inheriting it from `forms.Form`, and got an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (person_document_type, person_document_number, person_name) specified for Contract
```

Is there any beautiful way to do it (without copying these fields to all my model forms)?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197-solving-the-metaclass-conflict/ Check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just implement PersonForm with ModelForm?

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    person_name = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Entregado por',
        max_length=64,
    )
    person_document_number = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Número de Documento',
        max_length=15,
    )
    person_document_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        label=u'Tipo de Documento',
        choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH + list(DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES),
    )

class ContractForm(PersonForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contract

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContractForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['person_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'js-person-name'
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it seems so obvious :)